# All EC2 outbound traffic is blocked

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, linux-networking

This is access from WITHIN an EC2 outbound to anywhere. (EC2-BAD)

I can get INTO the instance via ssh and I can run my webserver on port 80 and I can ping from another EC2 (EC2-GOOD) in the same VPC. The latter EC2-GOOD is the instance I cloned.

Ping to EC2-GOOD from EC2-BAD using local ip address does not work. Nor of course to anywhere I try like github.com.

The security group allows all outbound traffic everywhere.

I temporarily modified the SG to allow all inbound traffic from everywhere. That then allowed ping to EC2-GOOD instance in same VPC via private ip address. public address still failed.

EC2-BAD is an image of EC2-GOOD. The same SG is used on both EC2-BAD and EC2-GOOD. Same VPC, same subnet.

Its an 'exact copy', what can possibly be different?

Thanks for your consideration.

Security group. sg-1e749271 is itself.

SSH
TCP
22
sg-1e749271 (linux-securitygroup)
RDP
TCP
3389
61.88.115.254/32

HTTPS
TCP
443
sg-1e749271 (linux-securitygroup)

Custom TCP Rule
TCP
4545
61.88.115.254/32

SSH
TCP
22
61.88.115.254/32

Custom TCP Rule
TCP
4545
sg-1e749271 (linux-securitygroup)

HTTP
TCP
80
61.88.115.254/32
MYSQL

TCP
3306
sg-1e749271 (linux-securitygroup)

HTTPS
TCP
443
61.88.115.254/32

HTTP
TCP
80
sg-1e749271 (linux-securitygroup)

Comment: Could you add the security group rules to the question? Also, does EC2-GOOD have an extra security group that EC2-BAD doesn't?

Comment: Have you assigned an EIP to BAD?

Comment: Yes, you will likely need to add an Elastic IP to this instance before you can get connectivity.

Comment: I have connectivity INTO the instance. E.g. I can ssh and http to it. I just can't do anything OUT of it. That is, I ssh in and then try and ping github.com and it fails.

Comment: Note that even though I asked for a public DNS, it is blank in the console. Also I added an ENI to which is associated the EIP. Is it that I need to attach the EIP to the EC2 rather than the ENI?

Comment: That is indeed the problem. As soon as I detached the EIP from the secondary ENI and attached it to the primary ENI everything started working - e.g. I can now ping github.com from ssh in EC2-BAD. And the public DNS now appeared in the EC2 console. But, why is this required? Why does the EIP need to be attached to the Primary ENI?